# BlackBerry Device Date/Time Update Listener?

Tags: blackberry, rim-4.5, blackberry-os-v4.5

Is there a listener in RIM API which can detect that the user has changed the Date/Time settings of his Blackberry device ? I need to catch this event how could i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [list of documented global events](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/What_Is_-_System_Global_Events.html?nodeid=1163085&vernum=0) sent by the OS.  On this list, I see one for "Date Changed" and one for "Time Zone Changed."

Comment: Many thanks Scott, this is exactly what i was searching for :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also try RealtimeClockListener

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication implements RealtimeClockListener
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ...
  }

  public MyApp()
  {
    addRealtimeClockListener(this);
  }

  public void clockUpdated()
  {
    //it will call every minute
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a notification for time/date change .... it's like a periodic timer with interval of 1 min.

Comment: clockUpdated()

    Invoked when the date and time is updated.

    Note that the system actually invokes this method each minute.

Comment: i didn't find any other way to get date/time change notification. So i have used this method to complete my task.